# Function to change post status IF current user and post author are the same

Tags: post-status, wp-update-post

I'm looking to force a post to revert to draft if it is published by the author. Here's the function I've wrote so far:

```
function check_user_publish () {

$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$author_id = the_author_meta( 'ID' );
$postID = the_ID();

if ($user_id == $author_id) {

    $query = array(
        'ID' => $postID,
        'post_status' => 'draft',
    );
    wp_update_post( $query, true );
}} add_action('wp_update_post', 'check_user_publish');
```

Logically I think it seems correct but when I make a test post the status does not revert back to 'draft'. I'm testing locally using Vagrant and VirtualBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to find any action called `wp_update_post`. Are you sure it's a valid one? Lets try the hook `publish_post`.

```
add_action('publish_post', 'check_user_publish', 10, 2);

function check_user_publish ($post_id, $post) {

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    if ($user_id != $post->post_author)
        return;

    $query = array(
        'ID' => $post_id,
        'post_status' => 'draft',
    );
    wp_update_post( $query, true );

}}
```

*code not tested*

Comment: That seems to have worked. Thanks so much. Here is the reference to `wp_update_post` that I was using: [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post)

Comment: Funny actually, you're still using `wp_update_post` at the end of the function?

Comment: Yes, functions and action hooks are difference. Not all functions have hooks by its name. [Codex for available hooks and filters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_an_Admin_Page_Request) (not a complete list).

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain the "10, 2" here in  `add_action('publish_post', 'check_user_publish', 10, 2);` please?

Comment: Third and fourth arguments are priority (it determines how early the function should be executed, smaller is earlier) and number of accepted arguments ( 2 in our case) for the function `add_action()`. See codex https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action Let me know if you have further confusion after reading it.